# Performing action on swipe back (react-navigation)

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

In react-navigation, know there is a way to perform custom actions when the back button is pressed. Is there a similar way to do this when the user swipes to go back to the last screen?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm also looking to perform a custom function when the swipe back gesture is performed

Comment: @RichardMcCluskey Check out my answer below and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to determine whether the app is going back via the back button or swiping back with the getStateForAction function of the router. Play around with checking the action and state variables to fine tune it more if needed.

```js
export const ScreensStack = StackNavigator(
{
    Login: {screen: LoginScreen},
    Schedule: {screen: ScheduleScreen},
}

/**
 * Intercept actions occuring in the screen stack.
 */
const getStateForActionScreensStack = ScreensStack.router.getStateForAction;

ScreensStack.router = {
    ...ScreensStack.router,
    getStateForAction(action, state) {
      if (action.type == 'Navigation/BACK') {
        console.log('We are going back...');
      }
      return getStateForActionScreensStack(action, state);
    },
};
```

Comment: how to use this with react-navigation5.0

Answer (score 8):

React Navigation 5.7 introduced a simple way to do this without the need to override back actions or swipe gestures, basically you intercept the back action in the component and execute a callback before it happens:

```js
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

const MyScreenComponent = (props) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  React.useEffect(() => (
    navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
      // Prevent default behavior of leaving the screen (if needed)
      e.preventDefault();

      // Do whatever...
    })
  ), [navigation]);

  // Rest of component
}
```

In this example I'm using the `useNavigation` hook to access the `navigation` object, but you can also extract it from the props, it really depends on how your app is built.

[Official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/preventing-going-back/).

Answer (score 3):

Using this in react-navigation v5.0

So I am using `Pan-Responder` to handle `swipe-back` event in `react-native iOS`.

**So how I achieved this:**

in my Navigator.js I have added `gestureEnabled: false` functionality of the app.

```
const Funnel = createStackNavigator({
  page1: Page1,
  page2: Page2,
  page3: Page3,
}, {
  // headerMode: 'float',
  defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
    gestureEnabled: false,
    header:
      (<SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ bottom: 'never' }}>
        <AppHeader pageData={navigation.state.params == undefined ? data : navigation.state.params} />
      </SafeAreaView>),
  }),
})
```

so by above code I was able to remove back-swipe functionality in iOS app.

**now I have to add swipe-back functionality.**

```
  export let panResponder = (callback) => PanResponder.create({
  onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
  onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
    return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) > 5;
  },
  onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
    if (Platform.OS != 'ios') return
    if (Math.floor(gestureState.moveX) >= 0 && Math.floor(gestureState.moveX) <= width / 2) {
      callback()
    }
  },
});
```

so by using above code you will get a callback of `swipe-back` event in which you can add `navigation.goBack()` functionality.

**How to add PanResponser in you view**:

```
 <View {...panResponder(backButtonCallback).panHandlers}/>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some examples in the react-navigation docs:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/routers.html

I found that there is an immediate param on the action that is set true when the back is from swipe yet undefined in other types of back:

```
const MyApp = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
})

const defaultGetStateForAction = MyApp.router.getStateForAction;

MyApp.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
  if (state && action.type === 'Navigation/BACK' && action.immediate) {
    console.log('Perform custom action on swipe')
  }
  return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};
```